# How to deploy a Custom Page in a SP 2013 SandBox solution?

Tags: 2013, sandbox-solution, application-pages, sharepoint-server

Is it possible to deploy a custom WebPage in a SP 2013 SandBox Solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot deploy application pages to the 15 hive with a sandbox solution because the access is blocked. You can however, create application pages by using Modules for deployment. See this link:

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Custom-application-pages-in-the-SharePoint-2010-Sandbox.aspx

Comment: However, you cannot have back-end code on those pages.  As a work around, you can embed a sandbox webpart on that page.